# mysql trigger write file with dynamic file name

Tags: mysql, triggers, file-io

I'm interested in creating a trigger that will write a file after I import a csv into my table.  The file name includes a time stamp and my code isn't working properly.  Here's what I have so far.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER peachtree_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON peachtree
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET @sql_text = CONCAT("SELECT * FROM peachtree 
INTO OUTFILE '/srv/samba/share/peachtree_",
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y_%m_%D'), ".csv'");
PREPARE s1 FROM @sql_text;
EXECUTE s1;
DROP PREPARE s1;
END $$ DELIMITER ;
```

The set statement works fine outside of the trigger.  However when I execute the above set of code and then try  SHOW TRIGGERS IN test;  it returns an empty set.  If anyone could help I would be very grateful.

Comment: @spencer7593 has correctly pointed out that this is not a supported operation; also, even if it did work, MySQL triggers are always `FOR EACH ROW`.  This means that even if what you were attempting were possible, this approach would try to write 1,000 outfiles as you inserted 1,000 rows... one file after each row went in.  An alternative approach might be to use the trigger to insert/update a record in a new table, which could be read by a stored procedure periodically fired by the MySQL Event Scheduler... to do your export as needed.

Comment: Do you found answer for this?? same problem i'm facing??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/stored-program-restrictions.html

<snip>

SQL prepared statements (PREPARE, EXECUTE, DEALLOCATE PREPARE) can be used in stored procedures, but not stored functions or triggers. Thus, stored functions and triggers cannot use dynamic SQL (where you construct statements as strings and then execute them).

</snip>